# How to filter array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, filter

I am trying to create a function in Javascript, that will allow me to filter the skills which the different candidates have, i have been told that this can be done in Javascript, the function called "filterCandidateBySkill" is where i want to filter the candidates skills, but ive had a look of this and as the skills is in an array i cant find anywhere online how to filter it. a lot of them have filters for single words, but not for arrays.

```js
const newCandidates = [
  { name: "bob", skills: ["JavaScript", "Docker", "Ruby"] },
  { name: "ally", skills: ["Python", "AWS"] },
  { name: "joe", skills: ["JavaScript", "Azure"] },
  { name: "fred", skills: ["JavaScript", "Java"]},
];

function filterCandidateBySkill(candidates, skill) {
  // where im confused
}
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JS provides a filter method on arrays.

```js
const newCandidates = [
  { name: "bob", skills: ["JavaScript", "Docker", "Ruby"] },
  { name: "ally", skills: ["Python", "AWS"] },
  { name: "joe", skills: ["JavaScript", "Azure"] },
  { name: "fred", skills: ["JavaScript", "Java"]},
];

function filterCandidateBySkill(candidates, skill) {
  return newCandidates.filter(candidate => candidate.skills.includes(skill));
}

// Get only names
console.log(filterCandidateBySkill(newCandidates, 'JavaScript').map(candidate => candidate.name));

// Get entire objects
console.log(filterCandidateBySkill(newCandidates, 'JavaScript'));
```